# How can I use an int value as scenario outline examples

Tags: int, cucumber, gherkin, outline

I want to use an int as a parameter in my step, but using 
scenario outline examples, so for code:

```
And Skill Pop Up: Add new skill <skill name> with rate <rate>
    Examples:
  | skill name | rate |
  | java       | 1    |
```

should be:

```
 @And("^(.+): Add new skill (.+) with rate (\\d+)$")
```

But unfortunately it has to be "(.+)", in other ways step is undefined.

Is it possible to use integer in scenario outlines?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing "\" from \d

I tried with:

```
^(.+): Add new skill (.+) with rate (\d+)$
```

And is working fine

Use link below to test your regexp:

http://rubular.com/